# Spark - Group by multiple columns VS Group by an id created from the same multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is it a good idea to create an id from multiple columns and then make a group by ? Maybe grouping data by one column (the id) is more efficient?

Example:

```
my_dataframe = my_dataframe \
  .withColumn("my_key", F.concat(F.col("column1"),
                                 F.col("column2"),
                                 F.col("column3"))) \
  .groupBy(F.col("my_key")) \
  .agg(...)
```

Comment: I think it is almost the same. The shuffle (which is the most expensive step in the process) works with a hash of your grouping keys.

Comment: both operations involves shuffle and the one you mentioned might be more efficient but requires more memory foot-print.in my opinion, you will not get much benefit overall by doing as you mentioned.

Comment: one benefit which I would like to say from your approaches is better distribution of data after shuffle.

Comment: @kavetiraviteja not sure why would distribution be better, especially since `concat()` produces NULLs if any of its elements is NULL. Back to the original question, I don't see any benefit  of creating intermediate key, only extra cycles building and  instantiating new strings.

Comment: @mazaneicha thanks for pointing it out .. yes in those particular cases where any of the column values have nulls then it will be a problem and definitely would not be better distribution of data